# Printing an array vertically, within a nested for-loop. JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, for-loop

I was hoping someone could help me figure out a way to print an array vertically using nested for loops. For example, I have

[image]

to show what it should look like. Everything that is not that array, should be zeroes AND the dimensions of the grid is 10x10 unlike in the image i attached.

I would like to know how to print multiple arrays in one grid(the grid of zeroes)but knowing how to just print one array vertically is help enough! I am using javascript.

[image]

I am positive I am going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Just paste the code you have here, don't attach it as an image.

Comment: please post code. code image is not easy to read

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function printGrid(){
 var ships = [[1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]];
 var htmlResult = "";
 var size = 10;
 normalizeArrayForRows(size, ships);
  
 for(var r = 0; r < size; r++){
  
        normalizeArrayForCols(size, ships[r]);
  for(var c = 0; c < size; c++){
   htmlResult += ships[r][c] + " ";
  }
  
  htmlResult += "<br />"
 }
 document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML += htmlResult;
}

function normalizeArrayForRows(size, thearray){
 if (thearray.length < size){
  for(var i = thearray.length; i < size; i++){
   thearray[i] =  [];
  }
 }
}

function normalizeArrayForCols(size, thearray){
 if (thearray.length < size){
  for(var i = thearray.length; i < size; i++){
   thearray[i] = 0;
  }
 }
}


printGrid();
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function start(){
 
 var ships = [[5,5,5,5,5],[4,4,4,4],[3,3,3],[2,2],[3,3,3]];
 var foo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  for(var x=0; x<10; x++){
   var lngth = ships.length;
   
   if(lngth<10){
    var p = 10 - lngth;
    var rm = new Array(p);
    for(var i = 0; i<p; i++){
     rm[i] = 0
    }
    ships.push(rm);
   }
   for(var y=0; y<10; y++){
    var lngth1 = ships[x].length;
    alert(lngth1);
    if(lngth1<10){
     var p = 10 - lngth1;
     for(var i = 0; i<p; i++){
      ships[x].push(0);
     }
    }
    document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML += ships[x][y];
   }
   document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML += "</br>";
  }
 }

start();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 </script>
 
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <h1 id="grid"></h1>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not necessarily headed in the wrong direction. 2 nested for loops are a fine naive implementation of what you want to do.

In fact, a small change in the code you've already written, will output a vertical column of values in a matrix of zeroes:

Replace `+= " 0"` with `+= (" " + (x===2 ? "ARRAY".substr(y,1) : "0"))`.

The basic idea of your original code was to loop through each column and then through each row of that column. However, you would then output a zero in each row of the column. If you want to change the behavior in any particular cell, just add an if statement to check that you are in the correct row or column then, then change the value you print accordingly.

In the following snippet, I change the order of y and x; then on each row, when in column 2 `(x===2)`, I tell it to output the y'th letter of the word array `"ARRAY".substr(y,1)`. This achieves what you posted in your picture:

```js
    var ships = [[5,5,5,5,5],[4,4,4,4],[3,3,3],[2,2],[3,3,3]];
 var foo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
 for(var y=0; y<10; y++){
     document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML += "<br />";
  for(var x=0; x<10; x++){
   document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML += (" " + (x===2 ? ("ARRAY".substr(y,1) || "0") : "0"));
  }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 </script>
 
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <h1 id="grid"></h1>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to print something else in the cell, just change your if statement to decide what to print depending on the X and Y value.

EDIT:
Changed `"ARRAY".substr(y,1)` to `("ARRAY".substr(y,1) || "0")`; so that when the word "ARRAY" is done printing, it will just print "0" for the rest of that column; to match your picture.

CLARIFICATION:
`(x===2 ? ("ARRAY".substr(y,1) || "0") : "0")` is short hand for "IF x IS EQUAL TO 2: output the y'th character in "ARRAY" or "0" if that fails; else, IF x IS NOT EQUAL TO 2: output "0".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10165484)

Comment: Fair enough. But neither did any of the other answers; they just provide code snippets with no clear explanation. I was in a rush, so I just posted a basic description with a plan to explain it later. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: In the future be sure to add some description, since short answers get brought up in the review automatically, and reviewers tend to sort them for deletion